# making page with ajax loaded parts indexable for google

Tags: jquery, soa

I have a page:

```
www.example.com/?Id=1
```

Parts of it are bootstrapped using a jquery ajax Get requests like this:

```
$.get(
'/Home/GetContent',
{ Id: Id },
function (response) {
   $("#Content").text(response);
}
);
```

The content html is:

```
<p id="Content"></p>
```

I would like enable this page to be google indexable. Unfortunately, I cannot see how given google's guide:

[Google's guide](https://developers.google.com/webmasters/ajax-crawling/docs/specification)

can be applied to my situation. Any feedback would be very much appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: I wonder *why* you're using AJAX get requests for your content. If the content is constantly changing, then Google's index will be constantly inaccurate. And if the content *isn't* changing constantly, you probably shouldn't use AJAX anyway.

Comment: How else would you show a page fast and then load 'slow partial content'?

Comment: Stylesheets. Content isn't that heavy; the difference in download times between 20KB of text and 30KB is negligible. If you really have 60KB or more of textual content to show, you probably shouldn't be putting it all on one page. The exception would be hundreds of rows of tabular data, which you really don't need Google to index anyhow.

Comment: How about text that is extracted from an external source and needs a while to be loaded? I do not want to go into details but ajax makes perfect sense to me.

Answer (score 2):

Search indexing single page apps is a hassle. We decided that in order to index our SPA, we will have a nodejs express.js server, which on any connection checks for user-agent

```
req.headers["user-agent"];
```

and if it is Googlebot, then we serve static content generated with simple templating engine(Jade for example). I cannot think of easier way to solve this problem and I would love to hear a better solution for this problem if anyone knows it.

Answer (score 1):

I've actually used that guide for a GWT application and it worked OK. Basically what I did is make a component that dynamically generates normal (aka non-ajaxy) pages for certain URLs and that's what Google will use to index my pages. I didn't waste time trying to make the snapshots completely identical to their Ajax counter-parts, I just made sure they contain all the same text, the same links, images, etc.

Comment: This would mean that google would index my 'slow pages'. Hence, the user would have to wait a while which is not acceptable.